# Объединил два LIst и не могу вывести данные через ViewBag

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Я в контроллере объединил два List таким образом

```
 public ActionResult Device()
        {
            AD methodGetList = new AD();
            ViewBag.Current = "Device";
            ViewBag.Title = "Сеть";
            var adList = methodGetList.GetListFromAD();
            var deviceList = db.devices.ToList();
            var all = from a in adList join d in deviceList on a.DisplayName equals d.DisplayName
                      select new { a , d };

            ViewBag.NewList = all.ToList();

            return View();

        }
```

Посмотрел в отладчике, все нормально объединилось вроде как , но как мне теперь все это вывести в вид?

Пробую так

```
@foreach (var items in ViewBag.NewList)
    {
        <tr>

            <td>@items.a.Organization</td>

        </tr>
    }
```

Но пишет данных нет, без а тоже побывал такая же ситуация. Данные то есть

вот как выглядит в отладке
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`new { a , d }` - это объект приватного для сборки класса. Вид, находящийся в отдельной сборке, не может его увидеть - отсюда и проблемы.

Не используйте анонимные объекты для передачи данных от контроллера виду.